# Auto run a script to auto hibernate on startup

Tags: 18.04, startup, hibernate, autostart

I want that whenever my battery is below 20% I should get a notification and when it is below 10% It should hibernate. I have written the below code in "rc.local" but it is not working (The code works fine when run on terminal but I want that code should be executed automatically every time my Laptop reboots).

```
while true
do
    battery_level=`acpi -b | grep -P -o '[0-9]+(?=%)'`
    if [ $battery_level -le 15 ]; then
       notify-send "Battery is low : ${battery_level}%" "Hybernating now.."
       hibernate

    elif [ $battery_level -le 20 ]; then
       notify-send "Battery is low : ${battery_level}%"

    fi
    sleep 300 # 300 seconds or 5 minutes
done &
```

Also I tried to write the same thing in a .sh file and tried to add the line in "rc.local" file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the script into the `visudo` file? Because you certainly do need admin rights to perform such operations. Adding it there will ensure that it's automatic executed every time you log in into a user.